# Need sidebar to be closed when page loads

Tags: html, css

I have searched Stackoverflow, and google, but can not seem to find the correct answer. I need the sidebar in the webpage to be closed when the page loads. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the HTML

```
 <aside>
  <div id="sidebar" class=" nav-collapse">
    <!-- sidebar menu start-->
    <div class="leftside-navigation">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">


            <li>
                <a class="active" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
</ul>            </div>
    <!-- sidebar menu end-->
</div>
</aside>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#sidebar {
width:240px;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
background:#32323a;
-webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#sidebar ul li {
position: relative;
}

.leftside-navigation,.right-stat-bar{
height: 100%;
}
.nav-collapse.collapse {
display:inline;
}
ul.sidebar-menu,ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub {
margin:-2px 0 0;
padding:0;
}
ul.sidebar-menu {
padding-top:80px;

}
#sidebar>ul>li>ul.sub {
display:none;
}
#sidebar .sub-menu>.sub li a {
padding-left:46px;
}
#sidebar>ul>li.active>ul.sub,#sidebar>ul>li>ul.sub>li>a {
display:block;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li {
background:#28282e;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li a {
font-size:12px;
padding-top:13px;
padding-bottom:13px;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.3s ease;
transition:all 0.3s ease;
color:#aeb2b7;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li a:hover,ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li.active a {
color:#1fb5ad;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.3s ease;
transition:all 0.3s ease;
display:block;
background:#202025;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li {
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
ul.sidebar-menu li.sub-menu {
line-height:15px;
}
ul.sidebar-menu ul.sub li {
border-bottom:none;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a span {
display:inline-block;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a {
color:#aeb2b7;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
padding:18px 0 18px 25px;
font-size:12px;
outline:none;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.3s ease;
transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active,ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover,ul.sidebar-menu li       a:focus {
background:#28282e;
color:#1FB5AD;
display:block;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition:all 0.3s ease;
transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a i {
font-size:15px;
padding-right:6px;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover i,ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus i {
color:#1fb5ad;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active i {
color:#1fb5ad;
}
.mail-info,.mail-info:hover {
margin:-3px 6px 0 0;
font-size: 11px;
}
.wrapper {
display:inline-block;
margin-top:80px;
padding:15px;
width:100%;

}
#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left: 240px;
overflow: scroll;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 250px;
}
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: does this need to be pure css? can u run a javascript command on page load (or (document).ready if jQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set to you sidebar selector style `display: none;` and then use jQuery or JS. Once the DOM is loaded change the style to `display: block;`. It's easy.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#id_of_your_sidebar').css('display', 'block');
    // or $('#id_of_your_sidebar').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using JavaScript/jQuery, then just:

add this to your css:

```
#sidebar
    margin-left: -2000px;
}
.show {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

And then add a button to your HTML for toggling the sidebar (hide/show):

```
<a id="open" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

And finally this small three-line jQuery script:

```
$('#open').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass("show"); //you can list several class names 
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/56/

---

The negative margin moves the sidebar away from viewport and when you click on the button, the margin is set to 0px again giving it that slide-in/slide-out effect.